# can't remove the slime when it health below 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to make the slime gone after is hp is 0 or lower than 0 but when i attack it, it didn't gone but the hp keep going down by -
I try to change the Destroy code but it still didn't work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;

    public float Health {
        set {
            health = value;

            if(health <= 0) {
                Defeated();
            }
        }
        get {
            return health;
        }
    }

    public float health = 1;

    private void Start() {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void Defeated(){
        animator.SetTrigger("Defeated");
    }

    public void RemoveEnemy() {
        
       Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

Comment: when you attack are you setting `Health` or `health`? ;) Make it `private float health = 1f;` to be sure the only way of changing the health is actually going through the property `Health` ;) Otherwise the setter of it is of course never called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't call `RemoveEnemy()`. You need to wait to play the 'Defeated' animation, then call `RemoveEnemy()`.

If you know the animation's length, you can change `Defeated()` to a coroutine and wait for it, like:

```
private IEnumerator Defeated()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("Defeated");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_defeatedAnimLength);
    RemoveEnemy();
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a trigger in the animation, which will call `RemoveEnemy()` from the animation.

Comment: i try it but it did'nt work but i fix it using other way so thanks for you help

Comment: @PBGgming you shouldn't mark answers as accepted if they don't solve your issues ^^

Comment: @PBGaming what didn't work, so I can edit it, and others who find this question will get a valid answer.